# Passing HTML content to a ASP.NET MVC core view component (Content projection)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use a view component to create a component for a dialog element.
So the most of the HTML for the element is fixed (like the dialog element, the close button etc), but the content (what I want to show in the dialog itself) is different for every instance.

So what I want to do is bring the different content to the view component.
I know I can put it in a model, like this

```
<vc:dialog data=@Model></vc:dialog>
```

but then I have to capture all different possibilities of HTML in a model/object structure.
And the HTML can differ from 1 line of text to 5 lines of text to header/body/footer to 5 charts with text.

Now in Angular components, I can do this:

```
<vc:dialog>
 1 line of HTML
</vc:dialog>

<vc:dialog>
 5 lines of HTML
</vc:dialog>

<vc:dialog>
 100 lines of HTML
</vc:dialog>
```

and in the component itself, you can use that HTML (it's called content projection).

Is there a way to accomplish this is in a view component?

EDIT
I just saw a piece about Razor components (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) where this can be done, but Razor components are Blazor only?)

Comment: You're probably actually looking for a tag helper here, which *will* allow you to have HTML within the tags. View components do not support this.

Comment: Correct, I think we can use it. HTML is placed in variables I guess? Or I need to load an external cshtml file in the taghelper? Got it to work, but feels a bit clunky.

Comment: No. With a tag helper, you can drop HTML content right between the opening and closing tags, just like any HTML tag. Depending on whether or not you need to operate on that HTML content inside, you can load the "child content" from within the tag helper and do what you need to there.

Comment: Tried the tag helper, works like a charm for this case. Can @ChrisPratt make this an answer?